# Understanding the relationship between a distribution, an event, and a random variable

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm watching some [MOOC cryptography videos](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto) and the lecturer is covering a bit of discrete probability theory. It's been a while since I covered any probability and this is a bit more advanced than what I learned. (Stanford's "basic" discrete math is apparently more than the one I had)

I want to make sure I get these concepts here, so my question is:

**Q:** Is the below a reasonable working understanding of the gist of a probability distribution, event, discrete random variable, and random algorithm? Some of the notation is a bit confusing.

I'm going to assume I made mistakes so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

- A *probability distribution* defines a function mapping events to a range $[0,1]$
- An *event* is a subset of the sample space (are the objects in the set considered equivalent?)
- The probability of anything from an event set occurring is the sum of the probabilities of its elements (naturally)
- The probability of a union of events is bounded above by the sum of their probabilities (union bound / Boole's inequality, seems straightforward)
- A *discrete random variable* is a function mapping a value from $U$ to some other set $V$ (it is said to "take values in V" -- why "take"?) and it defines a distribution on $V$
- $Pr[X=x]$ represents the probability that event x will occur under the probability distribution defined by random variable (function) $X$ (I'm especially interested in getting this right since he seems to use this syntax a lot)
- A *uniform random variable* is a random variable whose probabilities are all $1/|U|$ (simple enough)
- The notation for a uniform random variable is $r \xleftarrow R U$ -- what does the $R$ represent here?
- A randomized algorithm has an implicit parameter $r$ (a random variable).
- A randomized algorithm points to a region of outputs (this matches with Shannon's "region of uncertainty" for signals in n-space, so that makes sense)
- The output of a randomized algorithm is a random variable taken from the codomain, representing a probability distribution over a subset of the codomain. (I think?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> - A *probability distribution* defines a function mapping events to a range $[0,1]$

Yes, the function maps *subsets of the sample space* (events) to that real interval.   Further it is required that the probability measure for the entire sample space equals $1$, and the probability measure for the empty set equals zero.

> - An *event* is a set of (equivalent?) objects

An *event* is a subset of the *sample space*; a set of outcomes.

> - The probability of anything from an event set occurring is the sum of the probabilities of its elements (naturally)

Well, that works for sample spaces of *countable many* outcomes.

More generally, the probability for any union of pairwise disjoint events is the sum of the probabilities for each event.

$$\forall A\subseteq U~\forall B\subseteq U: \Big(~A\cap B=\emptyset \to \big(\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)\big)~\Big)$$

> - The probability of a union of events is bounded above by the sum of their probabilities (union bound / Boole's inequality, seems straightforward)

Yes.   Even when such events *may* not be disjoint, the probability for their union cannot be greater than the sum of their probabilities.

$$\mathsf P(\bigcup_i E_i) \leq \sum_i \mathsf P(E_i)$$

> - A *discrete random variable* is a function mapping a value from $U$ to some other set $V$ (it is said to "take values in V" -- why "take"?) and it defines a distribution on $V$

Well, if $U$ is the *sample space*, $V$ some *measure space*, and the image only contains *countably many* values, then that is so.   Outcomes are said to 'take values', in the sense that they are assigned them by this mapping.

> - $Pr[X=x]$ represents the probability that event x will occur under the probability distribution defined by random variable (function) $X$ (I'm especially interested in getting this right since he seems to use this syntax a lot)

Then we'll take it slow.

- $X$ is a discrete random variable.   It is a function of the sample space ($U$) mapping to measure space $V$.   It is to be understood that $X$ on its own stands for: the measure of the outcome which is realised (ie: that "happens") .
- $x$ is a value in that measure space.
- $X=x$ is an event.

  It is shorthand for the event $\{\omega\in U: X(\omega)=x\}$, the set of all outcomes *taking* value $x$ (ie: all outcomes with an $X$-measure of $x$).
- And so $\Pr(X=x)$ is the probability for that event.

> - A *uniform random variable* is a random variable whose probabilities are all $1/|U|$ (simple enough)

That is for a *uniform discrete random variable*.   Later you will meet *uniform continuous random variables* which have a *similar* definition.

> - The notation for a uniform random variable is $r \xleftarrow R U$ -- what does the $R$ represent here?

"Selected at Random", presumably.   I am not familiar with this notation.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. One thing I'm not clear on -- a random variable has a probability distribution attached, but according to the wiki entry it doesn't return a probability, it returns a quantity of outcomes in the sample space. So a random variable is a single-valued function that returns the "size" of some outcome? Since outcomes are in event sets, how does a RV relate to events, if it deals directly with outcomes?

Comment: Also, does a random variable *define* the set of events under consideration? i.e. in the probability space (U, E, P) where E represents the (family of?) events, is E defined by some random variable that is implied but not given in the above notation?